# What does "have been through two or three jobs" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand the implication of this sentence. Why won't they have to cope with more expensive borrowing? Does a finance director have to borrow money to be through a job?

"First, it creates complacency. A homeowner with a mortgage could easily be getting close to 40 without ever having seen a rate rise. **A finance director could have been through two or three jobs without ever having to cope with more expensive borrowing.**"

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/3-reasons-why-the-bank-of-england-should-raise-interest-rates-for-the-first-time-in-a-decade-2017-07-04

Comment: For greater clarity **without ever having to cope** should read **without ever having had to cope.** The absence of need to cope was in the recent past, during the period of flat interest rates.  In the future please do not begin your excerpts with an unexplained pronoun,  "First, **it*....". Quote the previous sentence to provide the antecedent for the pronoun.

Comment: It means the guy has had two or three jobs and never experienced this situation. The grammar is fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase does not mean the finance director will not have to cope with expensive borrowing. It means that for a long time they **have not had** to cope with it.

A finance director could have "been through two or three jobs" - which means they have maybe worked in two or three different places, presumably for several years. In this whole time there was not one situation when they had to deal with a challenge caused by expensive borrowing.

This is what causes the complacency mentioned at the start of the paragraph, meaning ["a feeling of quiet pleasure or security, often while unaware of some potential danger"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/complacency?s=t).

Comment: finance direction is French. You mean management.

Comment: @Lambie, it seems not, if we trust Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_financial_officer. Also, I was only quoting the original phrase.

Comment: You said the phrase does not mean the finance direction will not have to cope. Finance direction is not a proper term in English. And it is not in the link, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Lambie, you're right, I hadn't realised what you were referring to was a typo: direction instead of director. Fixed now.

Comment: @Weathervane OK, now it works.